# Не ведется error.log apache2

Tags: php, apache

На сервере есть некоторое количество директорий, в них находятся php-классы. Есть директория N в которой есть классы, которые нужно отладить, но в error.log ничего касательно их не записывается (в файлах допущены намеренные ошибки), хотя в других директориях ошибки ловятся отлично.

Что не так? Как сделать так, чтобы логи писались корректно.

Данные phpinfo():

- log_errors  On

  display_errors  On

  display_startup_errors  On

  error_append_string no value

  error_log   no value

  error_prepend_string    no value

  error_reporting 32767

Крайне смущают значения no value, но в php.ini там стоят значения по-умолчанию.

Есть предположение, что "поломал" все .htaccess, но после его удаления картина та же.

---

Попытался настроить логирование снова, в файле apache2.conf:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

php5.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
```

Все директивы, касательно html-ошибок и прочего включены, результат:

access.log:

```
46.62.83.9 - - [16/Jan/2016:13:06:41 +0100] "POST /dir/expected_catcher.php HTTP/1.1" 200 290 "http://site/dir/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2618.8 Safari/537.36"
185.71.77.5 - - [16/Jan/2016:13:06:55 +0100] "POST /dir2/demo_catcher.php HTTP/1.1" 200 250 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)"
```

error.log:

```
[Sat Jan 16 13:06:55 2016] [error] [client 185.71.77.5] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test_notification in /var/www/dir2/catcher.php on line 17
```

В expected_catcher.php у нас есть ошибка, ее не получается отловить из-за логов. Предположения касательно причин уже иссякли, ничего к сожалению не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Если другие директории это виртуальные хосты, то вам нужно смотреть конфигурации апача и именно виртуальных хостов. Там обычно прописываются пути к логам для всех хостов. Как найти файлы конфигурации можно посмотреть в ответе на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache).

Если это один и тот же виртуальный хостинг или вы запускаете как `CLI`, то смотрите куда выводится поток  `STDERR`.

И ещё важно какие именно ошибки вы хотите увидеть в логах. Фатальные будут всегда (если STDERR не пишется в `/dev/null` например), а остальные можно отключить в том числе и на лету через функцию [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php)

Вам желательно указать в вопросе как вы запускаете скрипты и что это за директории.

Comment: Скрипт, который требует отладки запускается по принятию сервером определенных данных, в моем случае транзакции. Директории - просто папки с документами. Сам скрипт рабочий, тк в другой директории, аналогичный скрипт отрабатывает на ура.

Comment: В конфиге apache стоит путь: ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log. Куда по идее, все и пишется.

Comment: @lamartire что это за скрипты и какие именно ошибки вы хотите отловить? Скрипт по крону запускается?

Comment: Нет. Скрипт построен на основе этого класса - http://pastebin.com/M9EvaP0u. Срабатывает он тогда, когда на сервер приходит определенный набор данных, в моей случае  post-запрос от яндекс.денег, который содержит информацию о проведенной транзакции. Хочется ловить ошибки в принципе, в частности синтаксические, ибо отладить класс не получается вовсе. Класс приведенный выше работает (находится в другой папке и выполняет свои действия на ура).

Comment: добавил в шапку темы немного дополнительной информации. Честно, уже не знаю, в чем может быть дело, а переносить из-за таких трудностей файлы в другую директорию - глупости. В общем, надеюсь хоть это будет полезным и поможет найти решение.

Comment: @lamartire надо смотреть содержание файла `expected_catcher.php`, может на лету отключаются ошибки. Попробуйте отловить фатальную ошибку – сделайте опечатку в синтаксисе и проверьте логи, а иначе сис. админа нанимайте, что бы все проверял

Comment: Разобрался в проблеме. Суть была в том, что в самом начале, было подключение класса, в котором были ошибки. Поэтому попросту скрипт не доходил до того момента, где нужно ловить ошибку, а выдавал 500. Глупости, которые заставили изрядно помучиться.